# Strange hidden span appear in Wordpress website

Tags: html, wordpress

I am managing a Wordpress-powered website for my faculty. Today when I share a link of the website to my student, I discovered that there is a hidden span element in the code of the site, and it only shows up in the sharing preview (Open Graph or Facebook Graph) if the content of the page is short enough

The span element look like this:

```
<span class="keys_words" style="display: none;">
<a class="links_good_rands" href="some random link">Some random text</a> 
| 
<a class="links_good_rands" href="some random link">Some random text</a>
</span>
```

I have tried deactivating all plugins and changing the theme, but the element persists. Google search results don't really help, either.

The website is http://ngoaingu.vimaru.edu.vn/. The code is injected at the end of the main entry content.

Can anyone check this out and help me get rid of this strange element?

[image]

Comment: Yes, there are two admins for this website, me and the head of faculty, both are using Windows.

Comment: Your website is under attack. This is a hidden SEO spam content attack. To get rid of it, try to scan your website from your host to identify the malicious file, remove all unofficial plugins, themes , install SSL certificate.